# How Do I Open A UIWebView On My Current Location?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView displaying a site with only a map on it. I'd like to open the UIWebView and go straight to my current location. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Here is some of my code -

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *viewWeb;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *currentLocation;

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITextViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize viewWeb;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Request Intel Site
    NSString *fullURL = @“http://www.websitewithmap.com/”;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    viewWeb.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    viewWeb.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    [viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
}

@end
```

My JavaScript code:

```
   // LOCATION HANDLING /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // i.e. setting initial position and storing new position after moving

  // retrieves current position from map and stores it cookies
  window.storeMapPosition = function() {
 var m = window.map.getCenter();

 if(m['lat'] >= -90  && m['lat'] <= 90)
   writeCookie('gps.intelmap.lat', m['lat']);

 if(m['lng'] >= -180 && m['lng'] <= 180)
   writeCookie('gps.intelmap.lng', m['lng']);

 writeCookie('gps.intelmap.zoom', window.map.getZoom());
  }


  // either retrieves the last shown position from a cookie, from the
  // URL or if neither is present, via Geolocation. If that fails, it
  // returns a map that shows the whole world.
  window.getPosition = function() {
 if(getURLParam('latE6') && getURLParam('lngE6')) {
   console.log("mappos: reading email URL params");
   var lat = parseInt(getURLParam('latE6'))/1E6 || 0.0;
   var lng = parseInt(getURLParam('lngE6'))/1E6 || 0.0;
   var z = parseInt(getURLParam('z')) || 17;
   return {center: new L.LatLng(lat, lng), zoom: z};
 }

 if(getURLParam('ll')) {
   console.log("mappos: reading stock Intel URL params");
   var lat = parseFloat(getURLParam('ll').split(",")[0]) || 0.0;
   var lng = parseFloat(getURLParam('ll').split(",")[1]) || 0.0;
   var z = parseInt(getURLParam('z')) || 17;
   return {center: new L.LatLng(lat, lng), zoom: z};
     }

  if(readCookie('gps.intelmap.lat') && readCookie('gps.intelmap.lng')) {
console.log("mappos: reading cookies");
var lat = parseFloat(readCookie('gps.intelmap.lat')) || 0.0;
var lng = parseFloat(readCookie('gps.intelmap.lng')) || 0.0;
var z = parseInt(readCookie('gps.intelmap.zoom')) || 17;

if(lat < -90  || lat > 90) lat = 0.0;
if(lng < -180 || lng > 180) lng = 0.0;

return {center: new L.LatLng(lat, lng), zoom: z};
     }

  setTimeout("window.map.locate({setView : true});", 50);

  return {center: new L.LatLng(0.0, 0.0), zoom: 1};
    }


    ;
```

Comment: Does this website with map have some sort of an api where you can pass it coordinates?

Comment: I just made an edit to my question showing a part of my javascript code where I believe the location is called. I use - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)viewWeb {
    NSLog(@"Got here!");
    [_viewWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getPosition = function()"];
}

Comment: I guess I am now confused at what you are trying to do.  Are you having trouble getting the users location on the device, or are you having trouble passing the coordinates from that location to your javascript or is the javascript having trouble using the data that is passed into it?

Comment: I'm trying to get the users location on the device without having to press a button to do so in the UIWebView. I pretty much want the user to open the application, the uiwebview loads and goes straight to their location.

Comment: Is there a reason for doing it with a web view? Why not use 'MKMapView'?

Comment: @Losiowaty There is a reason for using the web view. I don't how to to explain it very well, but if you use this html link (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiL9fiI7qnHAhUGlYgKHencBpg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2F&ei=kYvOVcvoA4aqogTpuZvACQ&usg=AFQjCNFuPY2Aj2NOPEsGecppA7LUkWB7YA&sig2=6RwOFam6sApwSES3QU7P0A&bvm=bv.99804247,d.cGU) inf your webview, it loads Google Maps and asks location permissions and then goes right to the users location. I want that lol :p

Comment: You can achieve exactly that with default iOS map view. There are a ton of tutorials about this, for example : http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-iOS--Day-19%E2%80%93Showing-the-User's-Location-with-Maps. Please, do more research before posting in the future.

Comment: I know how to get the user location in MKMapView. I'm not using any maps though. Just a UIWebView. I can't use a map because, well... it's complicated lol So, saying I can only use a UIWebView that shows this special map, how can I open the UIWebView on my current location?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get your location like 12.06,53.01. Then you can use here.com maps. To pass your geolocation you can go to here.com/12.06,53.01. Or you can just use MapKit as usual.